# Shutting Down Sharded MongoDB Cluster Cleanly

Tags: mongodb, cluster-analysis, sharding

I currently have a mongoDB setup with a mongos server, a config server, and 2 shards of 3 mongod (master-slave) servers each. I would like to ensure that when I shut them down they are shut down cleanly as to not lose any data that is queued or while the server is determining the shard to write to, etc..

What is the current best practice for shutting down a cluster of MongoDB servers?

Which order are things best to be shut down in, issue fsync, write locks, etc..

I'd like to write a script to automate this to facilitate backups, new code pushes, and anything else that otherwise requires the database to be in a consistent state.

Comment: I'm not sure of your exact needs but I believe the best practice would be to *not* shutdown any of the shards. If it's for the purpose of backup it would be better to take down the slave(s) and backup those, is that not an option?

Comment: what does this mean "2 shards of 3 mongod (master-slave) servers each" are you talking about 2 shards where each shard is comprised of a 3-node replica set?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These best practices are still really being cleared up.

With your setup here's how I would do the server maintenance.

**Backups**

Find a non-primary in each replica set. Perform an [fsync & lock](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/fsync+Command#fsyncCommand-Lock%2CSnapshotandUnlock). Copy, tar, backup. Unlock the DB.

You should be able to do this successfully on a replica set. If you're really worried, you can do fsync & lock and then a shutdown.

**Compressions**

You probably want to compress data at some point. The easiest way to do this is again to do an fsync & lock and then do a db.repairDatabase(). The repair command will basically do a "defrag / compression" for you. As above, this can also be down with a shutdown.

**Code pushes**

Ideally, there is very little that needs to be consistent with regards to a code push. At the worst, you'll need to manage index creation / deletion. But this really needs to be managed separately as you don't want devs just randomly adding indexes on a production DB.

**Monitoring**

This is a way more complex topic, but you'll probably want to watch for things like "who's master", "what the write throughput on each node", "how much RAM am I using", "how much data is shifting between nodes". There are limited tools for doing this right now, so expect to roll your own.